# Comparing a char pointer in an array with an integer

Tags: c++

So I'm currently working on a project where it involves two lora devices (Arduino Mega + Dragino LoRa shield) exchanging data with each other.

How it works:

1. Client will send the speed of motor reading to the server, it will also receive the distance reading from the server.
2. Server will receive the speed of motor reading and also send its distance reading to the client.

I'm kinda new in C++ programming and here is the issue. The value i received from client is stored in char type buf. How can i compare it with an integer so that i can proceed with a threshold?

```
if ((char*)buf) < 10){ // (char*)buf contains the distance value sent by the server, I want to compare it with a certain value to trigger a buzzer
   sound = 1000;
   tone(buzzer,sound);
 }
```

I recieved an error message error: **ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer**

Here is the sending code:

```
char data[3];
itoa(reading, data, 10);
rf95.send((uint8_t*)data,sizeof(data));
```

Any idea on how i can solve this issue.

Comment: Well, you're comparing a pointer to an integer, as the error states. Why not try `((char)buf) < 10)` or better yet `((int)buf) < 10)`?

Comment: What is `buf`? What is it's content (a number, a string, ...)?

Comment: @Yksisarvinen I believe the OP suggested buf is a character array.

Comment: It depends on whether `buf` stores the number as text or binary data. And in the latter case you also need to specify the size and endianness.

Comment: @h0r53 OP only said it was a buffer of `char`s, which doesn't say anything about how its content is encoded.

Comment: Show the sending code and the definition of the data it sends.

Comment: for the first suggestion, it shows a warning: **cast from 'uint8_t* {aka unsigned char*} to 'char' loses precision [-fpermissive]** but for the second suggestion it can compile and i uploaded to the board, but it didn't buzz.

Comment: so here is the sending code : `char data[3];
     itoa(reading, data, 10);
     rf95.send((uint8_t*)data,sizeof(data));`

Comment: are you sure you want `(char*)buf) < 10` and not `*buf < 10` ?

Comment: Question lacks lot of of debugging details. Please provide more code, explain exactly how input looks like and what is expected behavior. People providing feedback silently assumed that `data` contains number in text representation, but size of that array and way attempt was done indicates it might be something else (binary value)

Comment: Yes it is a binary value, the distance value which is the reading is actually a float. so i use the itoa() to convert it to an ASCII code and send it to the client. Btw, thank you tho for your suggestions and help, i'm new to this.

Comment: @IdilRahman "_Yes it is a binary value_" - No it's not according to the code you've shown. Is `reading` a `float`? You understand that the float will be converted to an `int` so all the decimals are lost in the `itoa` call?

Comment: Yes i acknowledge that. at first i wanted to send the float value to the receiving side but i just don't know how and i just stick with the itoa call and just let it be an int.

Comment: @IdilRahman If you want the float, I could adapt the answer to that. What precision would you like in that case? What is the range of the float? Min and max value?

Comment: The range woud be 2 decimal places. and other than that i'm all good.

Comment: Ok and what is the minimum and maximum value of the float?

Comment: I'm not sure about this but i guess 1.175494351 E - 38 is okay right?

Comment: Sure, but given 2 decimal places, that will be `0`. Ok, no negative values. So, what is the maximum value?

Comment: i'll go for the maximum value 3.402823466 E + 38.

Comment: `340282346638528859811704183484516925440.00` ... ok ... I'll fix that :-)

Comment: Oh wait lol that's a lot haha sorry tho. erm maybe 10000.00  since my ultrasonic sensor can reach up to 11m only.

Comment: @IdilRahman I updated it with some ideas.

Comment: Alright i will try it out. will update to you later. Thank you so much!

Comment: @IdilRahman You're welcome! Hope it works out. Another idea could be to create a class that inherits from the [`RH_RF95`](https://www.airspayce.com/mikem/arduino/RadioHead/classRH__RF95.html) class and put the helper functions in that class instead - but I didn't want to take this too far. With a properly up-to-date Arduino STL library, it'd be really simple to make a very nice wrapper around this.

Comment: @IdilRahman Any progress?

Answer (score 0):

Sender:

```
char data[3];                   // I suggest making this bigger because it is
itoa(reading, data, 10);        // now only safe if `reading` is in the range [-9, 99]
rf95.send((uint8_t*)data, strlen(data) + 1); // only send just enough
```

I suggest using `sprintf(data, "%d", reading);` instead of the non-standard `itoa` though.

If `reading` is a `float` as the comments suggest, you need to do this instead:

```
sprintf(data, "%.0f", reading); // there's no space for decimals in data
```

Receiver:

```
// read into buf until a \0 is encountered (and store that \0), then

int reading;

// if buf is an uint8_t[] as suggested in the comments, cast it:
if(sscanf(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(buf), "%d", &reading) == 1) {
    // an int was decoded
    if(reading < 10) {
        sound = 1000;
        tone(buzzer,sound);
    }
}
```

If you have installed Arduino STL you may have access to a lot more functions and classes that could help - but afaik, Arduino STL is very outdated so I used `sscanf` that I *think* is included in the base Arduino package.

---

Since you probably want to send different types over the radio and you'll have to cast between the `char*` and `uint8*` a lot, you could add two helper function templates to do that:

```
template<uint8_t N>    // returns true if sent ok
bool rf95send(const char(&buf)[N], uint8_t len) {
    if(N < len) return false;
    return rf95.send(reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t*>(buf), len);
}

template<uint8_t N>    // returns true if received ok
bool rf95receive(char(&buf)[N]) {
    uint8_t len = N;
    return rf95.recv(reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(buf), &len);
}
```

You can then add helper functions for the types you'd like to support:

```
bool rf95send_float(float f) {                // returns true if sent ok
    char buf[45];                             // room for all floats
    int len = sprintf(buf, "%.2f", f);
    return len > 0 && rf95send(buf, len + 1); // +1 for the null terminator
}

bool rf95receive_float(float& f) { // returns true if received ok
    char buf[45];
    if(rf95receive(buf)) {
        return sscanf(buf, "%f", &f) == 1;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then in your sender code:

```
float reading;
if(rf95send_float(reading)) {    // sent ok
```

and the receiving side:

```
float reading;
if(rf95receive_float(reading)) { // received ok
    if(reading < 10) {
        sound = 1000;
        tone(buzzer,sound);
    } 
}
```

Comment: It worked tho but it shows a warning : **invalid conversion from 'uint8_t* {aka unsigned char*}' to 'const char* [-fpermissive] and highlighted this line `if(sscanf(buf, "%d", &reading) == 1) { `

Comment: @IdilRahman Ok, so far so good. You said "_is stored in char type buf_" - but ok, then do: `sscanf((const char*) buf, "%d", &reading)` and it should work without warnings. I added that to the answer.